# Angular js post request in laravel returns null

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel, laravel-5

Here is my `post` angular request

```
 route.service('MetaDataService',function ($http) {


   $http.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

    this.newItem = function (url,data) {
           console.log(data);
           return $http.post('/'+url,data).then(function (response) {
               return response.data.status;
           });
       }

    });
```

**Laravel controller**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
   dd($request->all());
}
```

`dd($request->all())` returns `[]` array.

Also i've logged the data before the request (`console.log(data)`)it will gives the ouptut

**Request header**

```
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:en-GB,en;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,pl;q=0.4
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:2
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cookie:XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6ImluZmIwSmRNZ09MR0oxWEtzUzg0enc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiMXZLV1ZlN01YQm1jOVhvWXh4QlpuSXcxTVlSXC9jWStYYjlGWU5xeUFDWnhHQksrc0dvUzBhcFhvbCtFWVozSUxmNjhGT0s3aHRqM2UyV3hMZXJzR0dBPT0iLCJtYWMiOiI2NzIwYmQwMjAyODlkMmE0OTY5ODVkMTFhNmNkZTJkMTkzMDM2MjZmMWQ2ODBlNjJmODFhYjEwMzMwOGM5N2RiIn0%3D; laravel_session=eyJpdiI6InR3OURXNVNBRkQzcDM5TFlJMm9BaFE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiWHFOZG1cL2kzd3VFcDN1eWZ1SFk3WTRsM3Q0dmlRQzhuaVhaNHJzUzY0bTVpR2VrdVAwUkZPV0YzaHo4R01iSXB1QXZcL0k1QUVJejB2Y1wvM0JEa0xtdUE9PSIsIm1hYyI6IjFlOTU2OGNkYjM5ZmRlYmNmMGYwZGJiOGE4OTYwY2Y5YjFmYjg0ZDZkOTU4NjhkMmVkZjU0ZTkxNzVlYWRmZjAifQ%3D%3D
Host:localhost:8000
Origin:http://localhost:8000
Referer:http://localhost:8000/home
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36
X-XSRF-TOKEN:eyJpdiI6ImluZmIwSmRNZ09MR0oxWEtzUzg0enc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiMXZLV1ZlN01YQm1jOVhvWXh4QlpuSXcxTVlSXC9jWStYYjlGWU5xeUFDWnhHQksrc0dvUzBhcFhvbCtFWVozSUxmNjhGT0s3aHRqM2UyV3hMZXJzR0dBPT0iLCJtYWMiOiI2NzIwYmQwMjAyODlkMmE0OTY5
```

Comment: can you show us a sample data ?

Comment: `[name: "hello"]`  output of console.log(data)

Comment: @Demonyowh any idea??

Comment: are you getting any error in console like Access-Control-Allow-Origin?

Comment: nop there is no CORS issues

Answer (score 1):

Actually the angular js sends as raw data which could be retrieved by:

```
file_get_contents("php://input");
```

In Laravel there is a preferred or recommended way:

```
$request = Request::instance();
$content = $request->getContent();
```

OR

```
$content = Request::getContent();
```

Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

try to access as,

```
dd($request->json()->all());
```

Comment: Tried but returns empty array

Comment: Check weather `file_get_contents('php://input')` gives you something.
or you can use `$request->name`

Comment: Hmmmm... waiting for same.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the correct Request?

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```